# MIDI Synthesizer recording software in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-recommendation, midi, audio-recording

I know there must be 'n' number of questions regarding this. I also searched a lot but did not find any appropriate answer. I am buying a MIDI synthesizer keyboard. I want to connect it to my Laptop to record compositions and do some mixing etc.

What applications can I use to record output from the keyboard and mix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a DAW or Music Production Software, I recommend LMMS, Ardour, or Rosegarden as they all support MIDI using the ALSA driver. LMMS is by far the easiest one to get working with straight out of the box, but the others may offer different functionality. They all have a somewhat steep learning curve.

This sounding fairly opinion based, my favorite mixing software is LMMS, and I can verify that it does work with a MIDI keyboard to USB because I have one.